# Dictionary Add after Remove

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have aproblem with Dictionary. I am using this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

testDictionary.Add("1", "1");
testDictionary.Add("2", "2");
testDictionary.Add("3", "3");

testDictionary.Remove("2");

testDictionary.Add("4", "4");
```

I want the dictionary(keys and values) after this to be [1,3,4] but it is [1,4,3].  How can I do this?

Comment: Why not sort the dictionary like `testDictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Key)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered.
You can't do that.

Comment: Only if it is not System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary. or  System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary

Answer (score 2):

The order of keys and values in dictionary are unspecified. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx

They are, however, in the same order (i.e. the first entry in `Keys` is associated with the first entry in `Values`).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries aren't necessarily *un*-ordered (their order is *consistent*, after all, if arbitrary), but it is not something that you can change.

The reason for this is that a dictionary is a hashmap, which hashes its keys into memory addresses, or locations in a hash table, depending on your implementation. This is why dictionary lookups are so fast, and why you can only have unique dictionary keys.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more information!

Comment: Actually, their order is not guaranteed to be consistent; it can change when the dictionary is resized.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

testDictionary.Add("1", "1");
testDictionary.Add("2", "2");
testDictionary.Add("3", "3");

testDictionary.Remove("2");

Dictionary<string, string> tempDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string key  in tempDictionary.Keys )
{
    tempDictionary.Add(key, tempDictionary[key]);
}

testDictionary = tempDictionary;

testDictionary.Add("4", "4");
```

Comment: An explanation of your rational **why** this is an answer would be nice. Having only a code block without any reasoning is not a good answer, regardless of code quality.